# Error Opening IPython Notebook

Tags: python, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook

I am having trouble opening the IPython notebook and I am getting this final error. I am using Ubuntu.

> OSError: /home/tash/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/libzmq.so: undefined symbol: _ZTVNSt7__cxx1118basic_stringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE

I have tried to reinstall python, IPython, and also installed anaconda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with "zmq" package 
maybe (http://pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/zmq.html)

can you try to move this folder, and see it solve the problem

```
mv /home/tash/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq /tmp
```

You can always move it back if you like, using:

```
mv /tmp/zmq /home/tash/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem you need to update the zmq package as follow:

```
pip install -U zmq
```